# Row is not highlighted after right click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code to highlight selected rows:

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">        
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ElementBackground}" />
        <Style.Resources>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource ActiveColor}"/>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        </Style.Resources>
 </Style>
```

but when I right click on selected row, it is no longer highlighted. How to fix this right in xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works well... One Transparent color made the problem:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">        
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ElementBackground}" />
    <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource ActiveColor}"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    </Style.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish the reason for highlighting. There is a difference between 'focus' and 'selection'. When you right click, it's probable that the row (and indeed the whole data grid) loses the focus, however if the row was selected beforehand, it will still be selected after right clicking (unless you have some code that explicitly unselects the row in such a case, but this is not the default behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it with this line
      `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource ActiveColor}"/>`